# Cannot read some part of CSS content

Tags: jquery, css, icons, contextmenu

I'm using context menu library from [JQuery contextmenu](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html) for my project.

One issue that I encountered is that I want you reuse their icons. When I opened their jquery.contextMenu.css file. I found one of the CSS entry that I can't read. I'm using notepad++ to read the file. I tried to change the encoding but no luck.

```
.context-menu-icon-add:before {
  content: "";
}

.context-menu-icon-copy:before {
  content: "";
}
```

Can anyone help me how to make this readable so that I can reuse it?

Comment: change content to `content: "\xNNNN"` where the N stand for the hex icon code

Comment: did you get any solution. I am also facing the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using Font Awesome for their icons.

> Font Awesome is fully open source and is GPL friendly. You can use it for commercial projects, open source projects, or really just about whatever you want.

You can find more information on how you can use Font Awesome in your project here: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/